# Изменение цвета javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток, подскажите с помощью какого javascript плагина пожно сделать вот такой эффект на картинках? http://nextype.ru/

Comment: Про какой эффект вы говорите? Про то, что при наведении на изображение оно меняется на цветное? Или то, что появляется блок с описанием над изображением?

Comment: Про изменение цвета

Comment: @alexfedosienko, так это и без всяких плагинов можно сделать. Они используют два изображения: одно Ч/Б, второе - цветное. Чтоб сомнений не было:

   1. http://nextype.ru/uploads/images/chelstyle_1-2.jpg
   2. http://nextype.ru/uploads/images/chelstyle_1-1.jpg

При наведении - просто меняют путь к изображению. Всего-то делов. )

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, сделал спрайтом.

Comment: > сделал спрайтом

@alexfedosienko, Тоже вариант ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да там на самом деле можно и без JS обойтись, а только на чистом CSS. При наведении(hover) на блок менять его background (который, как вариант, в виде спрайта из двух картинок) и заставлять отображаться дочерний блок и подписью.

Comment: Можно даже и без изменения bg, и без js :)

Comment: css filters? Если да, то есть ма-а-аленькая проблемка:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters